# Is a subnet required for a dhcp.conf?

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcpd, subnets

I am setting up my `dhcp.conf` file for my dhcp server. All documentation says you 'can' define subnetworks but I have not seen and example without them. Definitions of a subnetwork say they are a network within a network. My network is only very simple with a hand full of devices connecting to dhcp server, I don't need multiple subnets.

For a dhcp server with a single IP range can I configure it without `subnet` statements? Or is a network with a single IP range a network with one subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just one subnet. Your configuration requires a subnet declaration, even if it's just one network.

```
subnet 10.100.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers          10.100.0.1;
        option domain-name-servers      10.100.0.1;
        option domain-name              "angelsofclockwork.net";
        option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;
        range           10.100.0.100 10.100.0.254;
        filename        "/pxelinux.0";
        default-lease-time      21600;
        max-lease-time  43200;
        next-server     10.100.0.1;
}
```

Comment: Is the `option subnet-mask` required? It can determine the subnet mask from the `subnet` declaration, no?

Answer (score 1):

DHCP servers can hand out IP addresses for multiple subnets so that is why they are being defined. Below I have the network 192.168.0.0 with the netmask of 255.255.255.0 which means that the hosts 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.254 are valid IP addresses.

```
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range dynamic-bootp 192.168.0.100 192.168.0.254;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.4,192.168.0.5;
    option routers 192.168.0.1;
}
```